# laravel eloquent lists - Sorting A List Of Column Values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Using laravel and I'm creating a select box on a form. I've been using the helper to create the select box and all is working fine.

I retrieve the data for the select box from a database and use the following to retrieve the data:

```
$data = model::lists('name','id')
```

Again all works ok and this returns the expected array

My problem though is I can't seem to sort this list - i've tried adding orderBy() but no joy.

Other than using a native php function is there a laravel method to sort a list?

Comment: Great question.  Normally need to put where's, etc on the query to create an array to populate a select with Laravel.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can put whatever you want, and then list it. I mean:

```
model::orderBy('orderByColumn')->lists('name', 'id');
```

As long as `lists` is the last method in the chain, other methods works just fine.

---

Starting from Laravel **version 5.3** `lists` is going to be **deprecated**, use `pluck` instead:

```
model::orderBy('orderByColumn')->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Comment: You could also use php array sorting once you get the array [PHP: Sorting arrays](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: excellent - thank you. I was trying to orderBy after the lists. I hadnt realised the order of these functions. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you @umut-sirin.  Much love from Detroit!

Comment: Worked for me when I switched the list arguments from `lists('id', 'value')` to `lists('value', 'id)` since it wasn't keeping the order by even though I chained it before `lists()`

Comment: When Laravel 5.3 comes our `lists` will be deprecated. It has been renamed to `pluck`. The method signature is the same. Please don't use `lists` anymore as you have access to `pluck` in current versions.

Comment: Hi, @DutGRIFF thanks for the update, is `pluck` already usable in the current version? Asking because i don't use `laravel` daily anymore. If so, I can update the answer to make it future proof.

Comment: @UmutSirin It is available in 5.1 but I don't think it is available prior to that.

Comment: model::orderBy('orderByColumn')->pluck('name', 'id'); not valid in my case. I found this solution: model::all()->sortby('Name')->pluck('Name', 'id');

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
$data = model::select('name','id')->orderBy('name');
```

If that doesn't work, toss a `->get()` on the end:

```
$data = model::select('name','id')->orderBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: Hi - I tried this also but struggled to implement the object in the html select helper the data was intended for. The result was correct but couldnt implement. Lists was easier as it contained the exact data I needed

Answer (score 0):

when I

```
dd(YourModel::pluck('name', 'id'));
```

I see it is Collection Class so I found collection laravel and then I found method sortKeys()
so I do:

```
YourModel::pluck('name', 'id')->sortKeys();
```